# Pipeline %>% in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to use the pipeline %>% from TIDYVERSE/PURRR to make this more readable:

```
myChargingDevices<-data.frame(fromJSON(jsonFile))
myChargingDevices<-myChargingDevices %>%
  mutate(myTime=ymd_hms(lastUpdateCheck))

myChargingDevices<-myChargingDevices[order(myChargingDevices$myTime,decreasing = TRUE),]
myChargingDevices$lastUpdateCheck<-NULL
```

Any ideas to do this more convenient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good thoughts. What have you tried yet?

Comment: Question is very vague, how can you decide what's the most convenient solution/answer? Can you make a reproducible example? `fromJSON` and other given objects  are not default R objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
myChargingDevices <- jsonFile %>%
  fromJSON %>%
  data.frame %>%
  mutate(myTime = ymd_hms(lastUpdateCheck)) %>%
  arrange(desc(myTime)) %>%
  select(-lastUpdateCheck)
```

I cannot test it, because you do not give reproducible code.

Comment: Looks what I was searching!